# Function PHP File and WP Enqueue Code Error

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to convert a HTML Static Theme into the Wordpress Theme. I need some help about php code mistakes. I am trying to include CSS files into my Function.php file but probably there is a mistake.

I tried to use some codes from developer.wordpress.com "function.php include css files" thread but they didn't work. So, I need your help for better doing.

```
<?php
function add_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate', get_template_directory_uri() . 'animate.css',false,'1.1','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap.css', false, '1.1', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . 'flexslider.css',false,'1.1','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'icomoon', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/icomoon.css',false,'1.1','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'magnific-popup', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/magnific-popup.css',false,'1.1','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl.carousel.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.carousel.min.css',false,'1.1','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl.theme.default.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.theme.default.min.css',false,'1.1','all');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css',false,'1.1','all')
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/bootstrap.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'google_map', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/google_map.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.countTo', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.countTo.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.easing.1.3', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.flexslider-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.magnific-popup.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.stellar.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.stellar.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.waypoints.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/magnific-popup-options.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owl.carousel.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'respond.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/respond.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
?>
```

The code structure in my theme and functions.php are above. In my theme, there are some .sass-cache files and also sass files. Is it because of this?

Edit: The main problem is that functions.php file doesn't fetch the path of assets. For instance: http://localhost/b2w/js/bootstrap.min.js is the path showed by the browser but it should be like http://localhost/b2w/wp-content/themes/fitpandas/js/bootstrap.min.js.

That's why all the assets have 404 status code in Chrome Devtools/Network section.

Comment: it's `functions.php` not `function.php`

Comment: Do you have those CSS files? All that code points to `theme_folder/css/cssfile` files

Comment: Yes, it is functions.php in my folder. And yes, I have all files. This is a free bootstrap html theme file and I am trying to convert it to php theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you name the file correctly. It is `functions.php` and not `function.php`

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/

**Update**

Also, according to the documentation, the 3rd parameter should be an `array` and not a `boolean`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

So the code for the first enqueue for example would be:

`wp_enqueue_style( 'animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.css',array(),'1.1','all');`

Even though, I don't think this will affect the result.

**Update 2 - according to comments**

1. opening `<? php` should be `<?php`
2. there is no `;` on this line: `wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css',false,'1.1','all')`

**Update 3**

1. `wp_enqueue_style( 'animate', get_template_directory_uri() . 'animate.css',false,'1.1','all');` needs a `/` before `animate.css`. 
   It should be: `wp_enqueue_style( 'animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/animate.css',false,'1.1','all');`;
2. same with `wp_enqueue_style( 'flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . 'flexslider.css',false,'1.1','all');`
3. `wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/bootstrap.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);` needs a `/` before `js/`. It should be `wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);`
4. For the ones that you don't recognize, they might be included from within the CSS or JS files and paths are not ok. Make the changes for 1, 2 and 3 and check again.

Comment: Yes, it is functions.php but the problem is remaining. When I check the paths of files, they don't have wp-content/themes/theme-name/css part. They have only, b2w(name of the wordpress folder in my localhost)/css/css-filename, so they don't see the path but code is right as I know?

Comment: Updated the answer. I did not pay good attention to the actual enqueues earlier.

Comment: Please post the result you are getting as an edit to your question and ( maybe ) the folder structure of your theme.

Comment: maybe try using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of `get_template_directory_uri()`. Let me know what the result is.

Comment: Okay now, something changed but not because of this code. I have started to my file with "<? php" instead of "<?php". I deleted the space between ? and php components. And something changed.

My local host gave the error... My codes are below:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'wp_enqueue_script' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\b2w\wp-content\themes\robust\functions.php on line 12
The site is experiencing technical difficulties.

Comment: you forgot `;` after `wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css',false,'1.1','all')`

Comment: if you still have issues, please post the latest version of your code so we work on the latest snippet

Comment: Okay, I put it bro.

Comment: line 10 in your code does not have `;` at the end: `wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css',false,'1.1','all')`

Comment: Okay now, thanks to you, I made some progress. But still, there are some problems.

You may find the picture : https://i.hizliresim.com/9Y1qo5.png

I noticed two things:

1-  https://i.hizliresim.com/mXy760.png -- > Assets' paths are correct. They have 200 status code.
2- https://i.hizliresim.com/Lvzg3o.png -- > Also, we have these 404s. And their paths are strange for me. I even didn't include such a path in the functions.php as you may see.

Comment: I updated it. But didn't change. Last code structure --> https://i.hizliresim.com/006NyZ.png

I think this is the problem -- > https://i.hizliresim.com/p538Er.png -- > One of them has right path and 200. Other one is 404, has wrong path. Also, it doesn't have a ver=1.1 part. Also, I even don't know what is that b2w/js/css.

Comment: I solved this issue --> https://i.hizliresim.com/4pobYp.png. Now everything is 200 Status Code and everything has right path. But problem is that content is not displayed.

Comment: Glad you managed to get it all ok. Regarding the content, go through your JS files and see where it hides the loading spinner. Maybe the condition to hide it is never met. Or, maybe, you have a JS error that stops execution. If my answer helped please mark it as accepted and in case you don't manage to find the error regarding the content display, you can start a new thread.

Comment: I marked the check sign. Thank you for your help. I will open a new thread if I can't manage it.